# linux serial port connection with cu command

Tags: linux

there is a network device on my ttyUSB0 port. I can access it with sccren command on linux, but when I try to connect with cu command I get this error:

```
sudo cu -s 9600 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 
cu: open (/dev/ttyUSB0): Permission denied
cu: /dev/ttyUSB0: Line in use
```

How can I connect with cu command?

Comment: You mean [this `cu`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cu)? "Bugs: This program does not work very well."

Comment: Use `minicom`. They are available for most of the Linux OS.

Comment: @Murphy, works for me very well. It doesn't have any interface clutter that plague all other serial utilities.

Comment: my problem is not connecting with any program. I have focused especially about cut command.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's just the file permissions on `/dev/ttyUSB0` that aren't set after connecting the device:

```
sudo chown $USER /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Or add yourself to the `dialout` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Comment: I tried both of methods but,  already get same error message.